# Connection to Android/iOS Bluetooth internet tethering fails

Tags: bluetooth, android, tethering, ipad

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 "focal" / Debian 11 "bullseye" with `blueman` and `gnome-bluetooth`

Hardware: Pixelbook

Mobile Device: Pixel 5/iPad Air with Bluetooth tethering enabled

I've been trying to connect my laptop to my phone's Bluetooth tethering to no success. The laptop connects to Phone successfully, but only as a headset device (and is capable of capture and playback for the phone, which is not very useful). However, the networks appears configured in Network Manager, but as inactive connections that cannot be activated:

[image: Network configured in Network Manager]

Attempted solutions:

- Various settings in `blueman`
- Installing `dnsmasq`
- Copying `/etc/bluetooth/*` from Chrome OS to the Ubuntu installation
- Changing device class code in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` to various combinations (which only changes the Bluetooth device class picture in Android but does not prompt internet sharing toggle.)

It cannot be a hardware issue since if the Pixelbook is running Chrome OS Bluetooth tethering works fine. Any idea?

Edit: I should mention that attempts to connect to NAP of the mobile device results in error "Could not find device `$ADDRESS`" despite the fact that it's already connected as a headset device.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you currently using? You mention 3 different OS in your question. Ubuntu 20.04, Debian 11 and Chrome OS

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. It's a multiple boot system with Debian and Windows also installed. The issue applies to both Ubuntu and Debian.

Comment: This is Ubuntu support, so if you want to ask about Ubuntu, Debian & Chrome OS you should be on SE *Unix & Linux* where both are on-topic; for this site limit yourself to the on-topic Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. You mention just copying some files from ChromeOS; but didn't give any clues as to what differences exist in the ChromeOS stack & Ubuntu stack (nor which stack you're using on the Ubuntu LTS release; given LTS releases offer two kernels stack choices).  Please be specific & remain on-topic.

Comment: Thank you @guiverc. The information I provided IS on topic. I'm not looking for support for Chrome OS or Debian, the information provided is purely for reference and contrast. Ubuntu is a Debian-based system and `focal` falls somewhere between `buster` and `bullseye` in terms of `apt` repository. The two systems, and specific software related to the issue, are comparable I was simply pointing out that the issue exits across the two, indicating that it may be a Bluetooth configuration issue. The Chrome OS reference is merely to demonstrate that it's not due to hardware incompatibility.

Comment: @guiverc I didn't include details of Chrome OS's `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` because it didn't work in Ubuntu, but I would be happy to provide two files if you believe it may help resolve the issue.

Comment: You didn't provide the kernel stack details I suggested; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the GA kernel stack option is using 5.4 (which yes is well ahead of Debian Buster's 4.19, but behind Debian Bullseyes 5.10), or 5.13 currently using HWE stack (ahead of Debian unless you're including bookworm) - ie. you've not given Ubuntu details I suggested providing, nor details of your Chrome OS where it works & thus is likely more valuable...  *drivers* is a *human readable* form of what are actually kernel modules; thus kernel stack details are somewhat useful; which I asked about if you re-read.

Comment: @guiverc I'm using a custom kernel based on 5.4 modified for Chromebook hardware using personal configurations, specifically kernel 5.4.123 from the Chromium OS R90 release branch. I'll be happy to provide the `.config` file if it's useful.